# Cut a 45 degree hole out of a mesh?

Tags: modeling

I want to cut a box hole out of a mesh at 45 degrees.

I'm able to do it with a boolean modifier, but it leaves a somewhat ugly mesh.

What would be the proper clean modeling technique to achieve this result?

Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: I would use the Knife tool in Edit mode. Note all the options that appear in the action bar while in use, snap, through etc.

Comment: Is that the best way to do it? Is there a way to make knife tool cut through the entire mesh?

Comment: yes, use K to activate Knife, Z to make it cut through the mesh, and C to make it cut perpendicularly to the view X and Y (or 45°)

Comment: Is this a final shape you need it. https://imgur.com/gallery/BfUAQ71